# Can I deduct mileage if I'm a contractor who works at home and at an office?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, deduction

I am a contractor and get a 1099. I perform some work at home, but much of my work is done at the office of the company I contracted with, and I drive to and from this office several times a week.

Can I deduct my mileage as a business expense?

Comment: Hmmm... interesting question, wonder why it got no responses.  I personally would think you can deduct this mileage.  Keep careful track of it.